# How to read response from Indy IdHTTP get

Tags: delphi, indy

I have written code to use get with indy IdHTTP component

```
var
get_url: string;
resp: TMemoryStream;
begin
  get_url := 'http://localhost/salesapp/is_run.php?ser=';
  resp := TMemoryStream.Create;

  IdHTTP1.Get(get_url+'v', resp);
  memo1.Lines.LoadFromStream(resp);
```

This url `http://localhost/salesapp/is_run.php?ser=v` return JSON response but I dont know how to read it from Delphi.

Comment: Is this a known format or you made up your own ?

Comment: You mean the PHP response ? I used `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Comment: The thing is that you need a parser on your Delphi client side, and I doubt that there's one for the raw PHP resultset. You should exchange data with the client in some known format, like e.g. XML, or JSON.

Comment: In case I returned JSON how I can read it from indy components ?

Comment: You run it through a JSON parser, like TLama said.

Comment: Any example about reading JSON ?

Comment: There are plenty of JSON examples. Where have you looked so far?

Comment: I am looking to read JSON using Indy, I can not find any yet.

Comment: You don't *read* JSON using Indy. You *retrieve* or *get* JSON using Indy, and then *read* that JSON from your Delphi code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When `Get()` exits, the stream's `Position` is at the end of the stream. You need to reset the `Position` back to 0 before calling `LoadFromStream()`, or else it will not have anything to load:

```
var
  get_url: string;
  resp: TMemoryStream;
begin
  get_url := 'http://localhost/salesapp/is_run.php?ser=';
  resp := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    IdHTTP1.Get(get_url+'v', resp);
    resp.Position := 0; // <-- add this!!
    memo1.Lines.LoadFromStream(resp);
  finally
    resp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The alternative is to remove the `TMemoryStream` and let `Get()` return the JSON as a `String` instead:

```
memo1.Text := IdHTTP1.Get(get_url+'v');
```